# The Atacama Giant

Tags: locate-this, chile, landmarks, deserts

I would really like to see the Atacama Giant. On Wikipedia it is just mentioned that it is in the Atacama desert. But this desert is really big. Where should I look when I want to meet this giant? It is soo big, that it is [even visible on google maps](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=19%C2%B056%2756%22S%2069%C2%B038%272%22W&hl=de&ie=UTF8&ll=-19.949389,-69.63407&spn=0.001568,0.00284&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=43.123021,93.076172&vpsrc=6&t=h&z=19).

[image]
Picture from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:The_Giant_of_Atacama.jpg)

So my question is basically: What is the next bigger city from which I can do a tour to the Atacama giant? Is it necessary to take organized tours? How can I get there? What does it cost? When should I go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just by looking at the map (I've spent some time in Chile but missed that), it looks like **Iquique** would be the most obvious starting place. A [city with 166,000 people in 2002](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iquique) and beaches has of course tourist tours.

Comment: Iquique also has a few hostels and many bus routes in and out, so it's fairly straight-forward to get to.

Answer (score 1):

Iquique is a good start point to get to the Atacama Giant. See [a possible itinerary to get there](https://maps.google.fr/maps?saddr=The+Atacama+Giant,+Iluga,+Chile,+Tarapac%C3%A1+Region,+Chile&daddr=iquique&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&sll=-19.932041,-69.65332&sspn=31.504107,67.631836&geocode=FfaZz_4dgnnZ-ynpKt1W7dRTkTEl_NvsveH_WA%3BFYSEy_4d8bbR-yk1mTb4Y_NSkTEwScmprqpXKg&gl=fr&mra=ls&t=m&z=11).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Travel.SE. Could you explain why this is the "best" or a good starting point? Could you explain what is the itinerary you link? We can see Iquique but what is the destination? the start of a hike?